# Dimple.js smooth animation of pie chart labels?

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

I'm using dimple.js to draw pie charts.

I want the labels inside the slices of the pie chart. I'm using a modified version of [John Kiernander's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28342150/1000026) to do this with:

```
    mySeries.afterDraw = function (shape, data) {
    console.log(myStoryboard)
        var ctd = getCentroid(data, myChart),
            s = d3.select(shape),
            degrees = ((data.startAngle + (data.endAngle - data.startAngle) / 2) * 180) / Math.PI;
        if (degrees < 180) {
            degrees -= 90;
        } else {
            degrees += 90;
        }
        if (Math.abs(data.startAngle - data.endAngle) > 0.25) {
            myChart._group.append("text")
                    .attr("id","innerLabel")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(" + degrees + ", " + ctd[0] + ", " +  ctd[1] + 4 + ")")
                .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                .attr("x", ctd[0])
                .attr("y", ctd[1])
                .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("pointer-events", "none")
                .text(data.aggField[0]);
        }
    };
```

The problem is that I **also** want to animate the pie chart, showing the size of the slices changing over time.

Using the above method requires that I remove and redraw the text each tick:

```
  myStoryboard.onTick = function (e) {
  svg.selectAll("#innerLabel").remove();
      }
```

So every tick these labels get removed and redrawn. Unfortunately, the time required to remove and redraw them is quite noticeable in FF (neither chrome nor IE will render the page at all), well beyond a mere flicker effect. Is there a hidden delay I can reduce? Otherwise, is there a way to either speed this up or smoothly animate the text itself?

The data set is very small, just 15kb, so I'd be quite surprised if it really requires so long to remove and redraw the labels each time. There are at most 11 slices to the pie.

I'm an ultra-beginner with Javascript, so I'm hoping there is a simple way to reduce the flicker. Trying to smoothly animate the text seems problematic because you would want the text to move in sync with the storyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post your 'getCentroid' function? I can't help you with a solution, but I'm trying to replicate the same type of behaviour and it would be very useful for this newbie.

Comment: You can look at the linked question for the full code.  The getCentroid function there is 
function getCentroid(data, plot) {
    var centerX = plot.x + plot.width / 2,
        centerY = plot.y + plot.height / 2,
        angle = (data.startAngle + (data.endAngle - data.startAngle) / 2),
        hyp = (data.innerRadius + (data.outerRadius - data.innerRadius) / 2),
        opp = Math.sin(angle) * hyp,
        adj = Math.cos(angle) * hyp;
    return [centerX + opp, centerY - adj];
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the code and it appears that the issue is that the standard storyboard playthrough is to spend half the FrameDuration in a fixed state and half the FrameDuration moving from one state to another. The problem is that during the motion of the chart, the labels were absent, so half the time the labels were there and half the time the labels were not.

I spent about an hour just trying to figure out how to extend the time in the frozen state through use of dimple methods, but alas I"m a d3/javaScript novice and eventually just broke down and rewrote the _goToFrame method:

```
myStoryboard._goToFrameIndex = function (index) {
  this._frame = index % this._getCategories().length;
  // Draw it with half duration, we want the effect of a 20% animation 80% pause.
  this.chart.draw(this.frameDuration / 5);
  };
```