# Add data labels in pie chart of dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

Here is my Sample Data

```html
Date HomeTeam AwayTeam FTHG FTAG FTR HTHG HTAG HTR HS AS HST AST HF AF HC AC HY AY HR AR
24-08-2013 Sampdoria Juventus 0 1 A 0 0 D 4 11 1 4 21 21 4 10 2 3 1 0
25-08-2013 Verona Milan 2 1 H 1 1 D 14 15 8 5 11 14 6 5 2 3 0 0
26-08-2013 Cagliari Atalanta 2 1 H 1 1 D 23 11 7 2 19 17 10 3 2 4 0 0
27-08-2013 Inter Genoa 2 0 H 0 0 D 20 4 5 0 15 9 12 2 2 3 0 0
28-08-2013 Lazio Udinese 2 1 H 2 0 H 20 7 6 3 15 13 4 4 4 3 0 0
```

I am using dimple.js to  create a pie chart. It doesn't automatically add labels(except the tooltips). I don't know which property or method to use to add labels to the respective division in my pie chart.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Pie Chart</title>
</head>
<div id="chartContainer">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.3.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="moment.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    d3.tsv("foulsandgoals.tsv", function(data) {
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.setBounds(20, 20, 460, 360)
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("p", "FTHG");

      myChart.addSeries("HomeTeam", dimple.plot.pie);
      myChart.addLegend(500, 20, 90, 300, "left");
      myChart.draw();
    });
  </script>
</div>

</html>
```

[I want to add proportion labels to each division like this(click the link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18pBx.png)

Comment: Could you add a sample data or url of the pie chart of which you took for reference.

Comment: I've added the sample data in the question and here's the link of the pie chart http://dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=pie_standard

Comment: Your question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306308/how-to-draw-labels-on-dimple-js-donut-or-pie-chart/28342150#28342150